# How can I get alerted when SQLServer is unavailable

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, alerts

I have setup alerts to let me know when SQL Server shuts down normally.  Now I want to add email alerts when it shutdown abnormally (system or process crash)

What is the easiest way to setup this secondary monitoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test connectivity periodically using [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) from another server.  If you have another server you can use SSIS to monitor a group of servers.

I've been playing with a program/webapp called [splunk](http://www.splunk.com) that can pull windows logs.  You can set up a query that will get your offending entry and create an alert for when the count increases by one.  It's free up to a certain threshold.  It's a very cool tool.

Answer (score 0):

A program like ActiveXperts can do service monitoring for you is you can't afford System Center Essentials.  But it will only report the service as down, it does know the difference between a normal shutdown and a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You might try orion from solar winds.  We use this to monitor our systems.  Works fairly well. You can monitor systems status, ac/dc status, some service statuses.  You can change the polling time.  It's fairly robust.